# script to remove all files in /tmp from a certain user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cron

One of my server daemons uses a lot of space in /tmp. Because I don't want to reboot my machine when the server runs out of disk space, I need to run a CRON script that removes old temporary files.

What would be good a way to recursively remove all files and directories under /tmp which are more than 1 hour old from user , say `www-data`? Of course it should not resolve symlinks and start removing files elsewhere on the system. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and will run this cronjob as root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop a script like this into /etc/cron.hourly:

```
find /tmp -mmin +60 -user www-data -delete
```

You may want to first manually run the `find` without the `-delete` option to check your work.

Hmm, also, to kill the subdirectories (since `-delete` only removes files), add in another line:

```
find /tmp -mmin +60 -user www-data -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Depending on subdirectory depth, the second `find` may take a little while to work its way back up, as mtime for the parent directory will be updated as the subdirectory is removed.

Comment: It should be `-mmin +60`

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici D'oh.  Thanks.  Updating the Answer now.

Comment: What about the cleanup of the empty subdirectories once the files have been cleared?

Comment: Updated with a directory killing line.

Comment: You will need to DROP the mmin +60 with the directories since deleting files below it will change the modification date/time.

Comment: I would suggest using `-depth` for second command to remove directories from the bottom up (to avoid warnings on nonexisted dirs and remove nested empty directories).

Comment: Is this any different from `rm -Rf $(find /tmp -mmin +60 -user www-data)`

Comment: @Jeroen your command is a bit unpredictable, in that the list might be too long for the shell, and it might throw a fit if there's a file with, say, a space in it.  Take a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls and while what you have is not explicitly there, it's just not a great idea to expand a list of files as a variable and run something like "rm" against it.  A different form for the `find` works better: `find /tmp -mmin +60 -user www-data -exec rm -Rf {} \;` and keep the filenames out of shell expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check with the command lsof if the temp file is opened before delete it.